# Why does ImageResizer always resize my image to 900 width?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-processing, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm using ImageResizer, I nuget the core and webconfig packages and did not change any settings and I simply have this line of code,

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, name, new ResizeSettings("maxwidth=1024&maxheight=1024"), false, true);
```

But the saved image always has up to 900 width or height instead of 1024 I asked for in the code, why is that?  My original image is 1600x1200, how do I resize to 1024x770?

Thanks!

[Edit by ComputerLinguist]

The OP is using the uEditor javascript library to perform the image uploads.

Comment: A language tag might be nice.

Comment: I've added c# and asp.net-mvc tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the original image was being resized on the client before being sent to the server, by the uEditor javascript library.

The OP was using the [ImageResizer library](http://imageresizing.net) correctly, and the library was *behaving* correctly, but it was receiving a image that was **already 900 pixels wide**.

The most *common* cause of a resized image being smaller than desired is when the original image is already smaller than the requested dimensions, in which case the ImageResizer will **not** perform upscaling. If you want upscaling, add **&scale=both** or **&scale=upscalecanvas**.

Comment: I downvoted this because there is no way at all to tell from the question how you arrived at this answer.  I don't know if you had a discussion offline or are just psychic, but no where in his question does he reference uEditor.  This magical leap to an answer that does not follow from the question isn't particularly helpful in the big scheme of things.  What we're left with is a poorly phrased question and a magical answer which don't serve much for the larger community.

Comment: We had a discussion by e-mail, and found out the problem was elsewhere. What's the appropriate thing to do in this scenario? Perhaps the question deserves a downvote, but why downvote the answer?

Comment: Edit the question and answer to share the knowledge you gained over email :)  Then I'll upvote both!

Comment: I edited the question, but it won't appear until it is peer-reviewed. There's only so much I can do.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://nathanaeljones.github.com/resizer-docs/doxygen/class_image_resizer_1_1_resize_settings.html), aspect ratio is maintained with the two max parameters.  Once 1600 is scaled down to 1024, the other aspect will always be much less than 1024.  If you want it larger, only set the max on the smallest dimension.

> MaxWidth [get, set]   ["maxwidth"]: Sets the maximum desired width of
>   the image. (minus padding, borders, margins, effects, and rotation).
>   The image may be smaller than this value to maintain aspect ratio when
>   both maxwidth and maxheight are specified.

Comment: I tried to specify only the width or with empty ResizeSetting(), I got the same 900x675 results.  So with ImageSizer how do I get the result I'm looking for which is 1024x770?

Comment: Thanks for fixing your answer.